# Comment utiliser l’expression « à manger / bouffer »?

Tags: expressions

J’ai entendu quelques fois cette expression : au lieu de « de la nourriture / bouffe » par exemple, « je cherche à bouffer ».

Est-ce qu’on peut la traiter comme un nom ? Par exemple : « Je veux à manger » ou « Je veux des à manger »?

Je sais que le verbe est « chercher à + infinitif » et pas « vouloir à », mais il y a des fois où il me semble que l'expression complète est utilisée plus comme un nom qu'un verbe - « je dois me trouver à manger » (le verbe n'est clairement pas *trouver à*, n'est-ce pas ?)

Comment: On ne dirait certainement pas *Je veux des à manger* (éventuellement *Je veux des à-manger* pour être grammaticalement correct, mais le style serait...particulier ;). Sinon, dans la phrase *je dois me trouver à manger" il y a bien 3 verbes; où "à" ici signifie en somme "quelque chose pour".

Answer (score 2):

Les expressions du style *à manger* peuvent être considérées comme des locutions nominales invariables. Elles ne prennent pas d'article et ne se mettent à pas au pluriel (<s>des à manger</s>).

Le pronom *quelque chose* est sous entendu:

*Je veux à manger* est équivalent à *je veux **quelque chose** à manger*.

> *Je dois me trouver [quelque chose] à manger.*

Aussi: *rien à manger*, *un peu à manger*, *trop à manger*, *pas assez à manger*, etc.

On ne la rencontre sans pronom qu'avec quelques verbes où l'on absorbe un aliment:

- à manger, bouffer, grignoter, grailler, becqueter, boire...

Il existe aussi l'expression idiomatique:

> Il y a [à boire et à manger](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/il-y-a-a-boire-et-a-manger).

Answer (score 2):

On peut l'utiliser avec certains verbes et au moins une construction sans verbe — les verbes les plus courants se trouvent ci-dessous. (*Les exemples sont tiré des livres, sauf exception.*)

- **vouloir** à manger (*Ceux qui veulent à manger, dit - il, envoyez la commande.*)
- **demander** à manger (*Arnaud s'était rendu dans la ferme comme Catherine l'avait
  supposé pour demander à manger, Gauthier était alors endormi dans la maison.*)
- **mendier** à manger (*Je vais aller mendier quelque chose à manger. Attends-moi là...*)
- **faire** (colloquial)/**préparer** à manger. (*Il dînait seul dans la cuisine – un sandwich ou un steak s'il avait envie de faire à manger –, puis il montait dans son bureau...*)
- **aller chercher** à manger (*Toi, reste assis, je vais aller chercher à manger.*)
- **acheter** à manger (*Plus tard, nous nous promenâmes dans la vallée au bord du fleuve et nous nous arrêtâmes dans un petit magasin pour acheter à manger.*)
- **aller acheter** à manger (*Il avait ses petites habitudes : tous les samedis, il prenait le petit déjeuner chez Estelle, puis passait à la quincaillerie, allait acheter à manger pour ses animaux, et terminait par l'épicerie.*)
- **trouver** à manger (*Il devait absolument sortir pour trouver à manger. Aller au restaurant était hautement risqué.*)
- **avoir (peu/trop/assez/suffisamment/rien…)** à manger (*Il luttait pour survivre, pour avoir à manger et de quoi se vêtir à peu près décemment.*)
- **donner/mettre** à manger **à qqn** (*vous ne viendrez plus avec moi donner à manger aux chevaux, et je ne vous enverrai pour votre dîner que du pain et de la soupe au pain, puisque vous l'aimez tant.*)
- **offrir** à manger **à qqn** (*Elle a décidé de leur offrir à manger. (user LPH)*)
- **faire venir** à manger (*Cela devait lui coûter beaucoup, car elles occupaient deux chambres, et le cruel hôte ne leur permettait pas de se faire venir à manger du dehors*).
- **commander** à manger (*(soit on commande à manger, soit on mange à l'extérieur*)
- **prendre** à manger (*Je vais dire à Winnie où nous allons et prendre à manger.*)
- **fournir** à manger (*Le loup, le corbeau et le chacal décident de lui fournir à manger et s'entendent pour lui offrir le chameau.*)
- **apporter** à manger (*Voici ce que tu peux apporter à manger dans l’avion si tu pars dans le sud.*)
- **servir** à manger (*Outre la discrétion qu'il offrait, l'établissement avait l'inestimable qualité de servir à manger à n'importe quelle heure du jour et de la nuit.*)
- **se servir** à manger (*Puis je le vis se servir à manger, rasé de frais et vêtu d'une chemise impeccablement repassée.*)
- **Voilà** à manger (*Voilà à manger  mais il n'y  à pas de pain. (user LPH)*)

*In all cases the indefinite pronoun "quelque chose" can be used right before "à manger" (the meaning is unchanged, but the verb has its usual meaning).*

- **prendre quelque chose** à manger (*Il y aura plusieurs arrêts sur la route pour vous
  dégourdir les jambes, prendre quelque chose à manger ou aller aux toilettes.*)

*In most cases it is idiomatic to use  in the place of "quelque chose" a COD that makes sense.*

- ... s'il me donne du pain à manger et des habits pour me vêtir ; alors Yahvé sera mon Dieu.
- Lorsque l'enfant entre dans son septième mois, on lui donne pour la première fois du riz à manger.
- Je ne me demande pas si j'aurais encore du riz à manger demain.
- ceux ci m ' offrirent ensuite du riz à manger
- Est-ce que les bœufs aussi demandent du riz à manger ?
- L'une des filles de Simon lui apporte du poulet à manger.
- Il dit "Préparez-moi d'abord de la pâte de manioc et du poulet à manger, car j'étais presque mort".

---

Il ne faut pas confondre avec les constructions suivantes et d'autres de la même sorte où la combinaison n'est plus idiomatique mais où il s'agit du verbe dans son sens habituel.

- **être prêt** à manger (*J'aimerais bien pouvoir le garder comme animal de compagnie, mais il va être prêt à manger pour Noël.*)
- **penser** à manger (*J'ai du mal à penser à manger avec un emploi du temps pareil.*)
- **être [pas bon/bon]** à manger (*Je comprends aussi pourquoi les poissons sont rares; de plus, ils ne doivent certainement pas être bon à manger !*)
- **inviter qqn** à manger (**qqc**) (*On va peut-être pouvoir l'inviter à manger des gaufres.*)
- **choses** à manger (*Elle venait des Halles, où elle avait enlevé « pour rien », prétendait-elle, « des tas de bonnes choses à manger ».*)
- **voilà** à manger (*Le voilà à manger des sandwiches aux rillons, accompagné d'une bière au maïs, dans l'atmosphère enfumée sentant l'huile de friture et l'urine d'un de ces petits cafés du centre de Lima.*)
- **demander** à manger (*Il est mal venu de demander à manger un plat différent des autres personnes même si tu le prépares toi-même ou de dévaliser le réfrigérateur.*)